# Use git-hash in building with cmake from C++ source

Tags: git, cmake

I would like to keep git-hash in output file generated with C++ source.
The C++ sources are build with cmake.
My directory structure is

main

- CMakeLists.txt
- sub_dir1

  - CMakeLists.txt
  - src
  - include
- sub_dir2

  - CMakeLists.txt
  - src
  - include
- common

  - CMakeLists.txt
  - githash.hh.in

The top level CMakeLists.txt add these sub directories.
I would like to use githash in both sub_dir1 and sub_dir2.
I tried to make the top level CMakeLists.txt like

```
add_subdirectory(common)
include_directories(common)

add_subdirectory(sub_dir1)
add_subdirectory(sub_dir2)
```

and CMakeLists.txt of common like

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
project(common)

execute_process(COMMAND
  "${GIT_EXECUTABLE}" describe --match=NeVeRmAtCh --always --abbrev=40 --dirty
  WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}"
  OUTPUT_VARIABLE GIT_SHA1
  ERROR_QUIET OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE)

configure_file("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/common.hh.in" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/common.hh" @ONLY)
list(APPEND SOURCES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/common.hh")
```

Then, common/githash.hh.in is

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
const std::string GIT_SHA1 = "@GIT_SHA1@";
```

When I build them, common/githash.hh was created.

I could load the `GIT_SHA1` in the source of sub_dir1 with `#include githash.hh`
However, the common directory is not touched after editing other sources thus it is remaining, not updated.
I would like to know the exact git hash of the sources when they are built.
How can I update the file in each build?

I know that this way which makes a file in the source is bad. Do you have better idea?

[Added information]

I found that the githash was updated when `cmake -S . -B build`.
I would like to update also just `cmake --build build`.
How can I do `cmake -S . -B build` at each time to execute `cmake --build build`?

Answer (score 0):

Using `execute_command()` only works during cmake configuration run, but not for each build run. Use a custom command instead:

```
set(GIT_COMMAND git rev-parse --verify HEAD)
add_custom_command(
      OUTPUT buildinfo.cpp
      COMMAND echo -n "const char* git_version = \"" > buildinfo.cpp
      COMMAND ${GIT_COMMAND} | tr -d "\\n" >> buildinfo.cpp
      COMMAND echo "\";" >> buildinfo.cpp
      DEPENDS xxxx
      VERBATIM
)
```

Add `buildinfo.cpp` to your source list and use `git_version` where needed.
In order to work properly, the dependency list `xxxx` should list most/all files that are likely to change frequently: use source file list (in small projects), or library/target lists (in larger projects).

Comment: Note that this answer won't work on Windows, which does not have the `tr` command. It might be better to write a CMake script that calls git and can be invoked with `${CMAKE_COMMAND} -P ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/make_buildinfo.cmake`

Comment: This will also fail when the build directory is not a subdirectory of the source directory

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much for your answer. Unfortunately, it doesn't works on my environment...
```
```

Comment: A part of the top-level CMakeLists.txt is 


```
include_directories(common)

add_subdirectory(sub_dir1)
add_subdirectory(sub_dir2)
add_custom_target(alltar DEPENDS sub_dir1 sub_dir2)

set(GIT_COMMAND git rev-parse --verify HEAD)
add_custom_command(OUTPUT common/common.hh
      COMMAND echo -n "const char* git_version = \"" > common/common.hh
      COMMAND ${GIT_COMMAND} | tr -d "\\n" >> common/common.hh
      COMMAND echo "\";" >> common/common.hh
      DEPENDS sub_dir1 sub_dir2
      VERBATIM
)
```

The common/common.hh hasn't been created.